# Create a default column filter at schema/database level in Oracle and SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

We have enabled versioning of database records in order to maintain multiple versions of product configurations for our customers. To achieve this, we have created 'Version' column in all our tables with default entry 'core_version'. Customers can create a new copy of the same records by changing one or two column values and say that as 'customer_version1'. So, the PK of all our tables are (ID column and Version).

Something like this:

[image]

Now, the **version** column will act as an identifier, when performing CRUD operations via application as well as when executing sql queries directly in DB, to ensure against which version of records the CRUD operation update should happen.

***Is there any way to achieve this in Oracle & SQL server? A Default filter for the "Version" column at Schema level that should get added as a mandatory where clause on performing/executing any query operation.***

Say, If want only "Core_version" records. Then, **Select * from employee;** should return me only 3 records respective to core_version without having the version column filter explicitly in query.

Comment: Well, you can create a view and embed this `WHERE Version = 'core_version'` in it. Then, make your program to query this view, not the table.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov if you read my question I want this to be done for all CRUD operations and not just for Select. And, there are 100's of tables in the application

Comment: There is no notion of a "default filter" for a table in SQL Server. You need to implement this logic yourself.

Comment: @alroc Okay. can this be achieved using Row Level Security in Sql Server?

Comment: Possibly, but you may not be happy with the performance. I think you need to take a step back, consider what your final goal is here, and the overall design of your system. It sounds to me like you've decided on a solution without understanding the problem. That, or you've painted yourself into a very deep corner via technical debt.

Comment: In Oracle this can be accomplished with Virtual Private Database.  But there won't be a single database-specific solution that works for both databases.  Maybe this is best handled by the application.

Comment: @JonHeller - Yes, I was thinking to use DBMS_RLS package(row level security) for oracle. the reason why I want to keep this at Database level and not in application is to manage versions check even when queries are fired directly against DB from tools like SqlPlus.